# Dev C++ not compiling. Error Message in compile log

Tags: compilation, dev-c++

When I try to compile any type of program, this message appears in the compile log:

`No binary directory provided in compiler set "MinGW GCC 4.7.2 32-bit Release". Aborted compilation.`

This is the only message that comes up and it comes up instantly without any effort of compiling. I checked to see if it may have been an error when downloading, but that is not the case as I followed through the set-up properly. Also, there was no choice to download for a 32 or 64bit computer so if that is the problem how do I get one that supports my computer?

I downloaded the Dev C++ portable version from this link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/?source=typ_redirect

I really do not know what the issue is here so I would appreciate any help and hopefully to anyone else encountering this problem. I haven't found anyone with this same error though.

Comment: is there s a bin dir where you installed the program?

Comment: @jgr208 There is a bin dir only in the folder MinGW64. Ok I believe I fixed the problem. I do not know how this affected it, but upon running the first time, it does not work. Then, once you run it on a different computer, you must go through a small setup which asks for font and style and such. Once going through that it only works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this problem before.

Here's how I solved it.

Go to: 
`Tools ->Compiler Options ->Directories ->Binaries`

Then choose "MinGW64\bin" as your directory

Usually, it is located where you installed this software.